# TYPO3 4.7 colPos doesn't work with TemplaVoila, need alternative

Tags: typo3, typoscript, templavoila

Im novice in TypoScript and i wanna know how i can get the content inside the second colomn of my TemplaVoila structure. I used `colPos = <position>` before, but its not working anymore. I show my TypoScript! Someone knows an alternative to `colPos`, if yes, help me please

```
lib.sliderThumbs = CONTENT
lib.sliderThumbs{
  table = tt_content
  select.pidInList = 2
  select.where = colPos = 2
}
```

Comment: Dont use Templavoila if you want to use the standard TS features. Use gridelements and fluidtemplate instead.

Answer (score 1):

First check if `select.where = colPos = 0` works for you at all.

In TemplaVoila (TV) when you're adding new `Page-Content Element` it's by default set to place content elements in `colPos = 0`. So nevermind how many TV column you have, for TypoScript all of them will be placed in `normal column`. To change this you need to change the value of `Old style column number` field in `Extra` settings of the TV for each TV column. As described in the TV wizard:

```
Column number (0=normal, 1=left, 2=right, 3=border)
```

You can also change it directly in DataStructure's XML of selected field with:

```
<oldStyleColumnNumber>2</oldStyleColumnNumber>
```

however I think that it will be just easier to use TV wizard.

Comment: I did what u wrote and the typoscript still doesn't work, i checked if i had the good pid and the colPos position

Comment: After change you need to clear all cache and reposition the elements ie drag it into the other column (with other colPos) and drag again to the original one. Or create new element in the changed column to see if it works. Otherwise it still has old colPos. For existing records you can also edit the content element and set required `Column` as `Right`. New records will be created with proper colPos by default.